# PHP - check string is staring from CSS/ or not?

Tags: php, string

I have strings like below :

```
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/gg-statics/style.min.css
css/gg_used_good_store.css
css/select2.min.css
css/jquery-ui.css
css/header-footer.css
css/kc.fab.css
css/dropzone.css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,600,700,700i,800,800i
```

I want to check if string is strating with **css/** or not ? I need **css/** if it's first occurrence. if **css/** word is in the middel of the string then I don't want it.

How can I get that ?

Comment: You might need to use `strpos($string, 'css')` which gives you position of the css and use accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strpos()` to find the position of a specific substring in a string.

`strpos($originalString, 'css/');`

The code below parses a file and checks if the first word starts with `'css/'` :

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if strpos($line, 'css/') == 0 {
            echo "Line starts with css/";
        } else {
            echo "Line doesn't start with css/";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "Error";    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is the right function in this case. 
It returns the position of the needle in the haystack, in your case, as you want to check if the string start with css/, the position must be equal to 0.

Then, using your code, you can do something like:

```
$a="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/gg-statics/style.min.css";
$b="css/gg_used_good_store.css";
if ((strpos($b, 'css/'))==0) {
    echo "Starting with css/"; 
    } else {
    echo "NOT starting with css/"; 
    }
```